# Execute AsyncTask in Fragment from another Activity class and update UI inside it

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I'm trying to execute `AsyncTask` from a fragment class `(e.g MyFragment.java)` from another Activity class `(e.g MyActivity.java)`.

the fragment class `MyFragment.java` is updating UI on it's elements :

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private SwipeRefreshLayout myRefreshLayout;
    private ArrayAdapter myListAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myListAdapter = new myCustomAdapter(getContext(), myDataArray);
        myRefreshLayout = myView.findViewById(R.id.myRefreshLayout);
    }

    public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            // UI...
            myRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // UI...
            myRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

         @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // code...
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to Execute AsyncTask from `MyActivity.java`

```
MyFragment myfragment = new MyFragment();
myfragment.new MyTask.execute();
```

The Application **crashes** at `onPreExecute` :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.**setRefreshing(boolean)**' on a null object reference.

I'm assuming this is because it couldn't access `myRefreshLayout` to perform `setRefreshing(true)` on it, because i'm running the task from another thread `MyActivity.java`

How can i execute the **AsyncTask** on the **Fragment** .. from the **Activity** and change the UI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Idk if this would be a nice solution. But I think you can make MainActivity implements this custom interface. It'd be a callback that should be execute after the swipe action done.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyAsyncCallback {
    ....
    ....

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyFragment myfragment = new MyFragment();
        myfragment.new MyTask(this).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute(Boolean isRefreshing) {
        if(isRefreshing){
            // UPDATE MAIN UI
        }
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Boolean isRefreshing) {
       if(isRefreshing){
            // UPDATE MAIN UI
        }
     }
}

interface MyAsyncCallback {
    void onPreExecute(Boolean isRefreshing);
    void onPostExecute(Boolean isRefreshing);
}
```

in your fragment

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    WeakReference<MyAsyncCallback> myListener;

    public MyTask(MyAsyncCallback listener){
        this.myListener = listener
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // don't forget to return view
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        
        MyAsyncCallback myListener = this.myListener.get();
        if (myListener != null) {
            myListener.onPreExecute(true);
        }

        myRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    }

    //same for onPostExecute()
```

Comment: The issue is about updating the UI elements on the fragment not mainactivity, as i said when i call the asyncTask from mainactivity .. the UI elements on the fragment throws the error because they won't be available to be updated when the call is coming from outside the fragment. i described that ```the fragment class MyFragment.java is updating UI on it's elements :``` .. you provided a very good example for using asynctask callback, that might help for other cases! thanks maftu!